# android.os.FileUriExposedException when relaying an Intent containing an Uri to a file

Tags: android, exception, android-intent

Basically I'm trying to do what "[Andmade Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andmadesoft.share&hl=en)" does. Replace the system share dialog by a custom one.

Under some conditions it works, then again under others it doesn't.

For example, if I go to the camera app and share a photo, my app is automatically invoked, and it shows a dialog with installed target apps which can be used to share the photo. So if I click on the Gmail Icon, which I have in a RecyclerView, then Gmail opens up and the photo is in the draft.

Buy if I try to do the same with a csv file from some other app, in my case I tried to tell "[Libra - Weight Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cachapa.libra&hl=en)" that I want to share the a backup, in order to send it to me via Gmail, then my app gets the share request (remember, it is replacing the OS-supplied share dialog), and when it then tries to start Gmail with the intent forwarded, then the error occurs.

This is the log:

```
03-06 18:24:45.756 E/SharerAct: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
03-06 18:24:45.757 W/SharerAct: INSERT INTENT: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER flg=0x10800000 cmp=org.example.android.my_app_name.app/.ui.activities.Insert (has extras) }
03-06 18:24:45.757 W/SharerAct: INSERT ACTION: android.intent.action.CHOOSER
03-06 18:24:45.757 W/SharerAct: INSERT TYPE: null
03-06 18:24:45.757 W/SharerAct: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
03-06 18:24:45.758 W/SharerAct: INSERT BUNDLE -> android.intent.extra.INITIAL_INTENTS -- [Landroid.os.Parcelable;@fa03561 -- ([Landroid.os.Parcelable;)
03-06 18:24:45.759 W/SharerAct: INSERT BUNDLE -> android.intent.extra.INTENT -- Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/csv flg=0x1 clip={text/csv T:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cachapa.libra} (has extras) } -- (android.content.Intent)
03-06 18:24:45.759 W/SharerAct: INSERT BUNDLE -> android.intent.extra.TITLE -- Datenbank exportieren -- (java.lang.String)
03-06 18:24:45.759 E/SharerAct: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
03-06 18:24:45.759 W/SharerAct: INSERT INNER INTENT: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/csv flg=0x1 clip={text/csv T:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cachapa.libra} (has extras) }
03-06 18:24:45.760 W/SharerAct: INSERT INNER ACTION: android.intent.action.SEND
03-06 18:24:45.760 W/SharerAct: INSERT INNER TYPE: text/csv
03-06 18:24:45.760 W/SharerAct: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
03-06 18:24:45.761 W/SharerAct: INSERT INNER BUNDLE -> android.intent.extra.SUBJECT -- Libra Database: 2017-03-06 -- (java.lang.String)
03-06 18:24:45.761 W/SharerAct: INSERT INNER BUNDLE -> android.intent.extra.TEXT -- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cachapa.libra -- (java.lang.String)
03-06 18:24:45.762 W/SharerAct: INSERT INNER BUNDLE -> android.intent.extra.STREAM -- file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/net.cachapa.libra/cache/Libra_2017-03-06.csv -- (android.net.Uri$StringUri)
03-06 18:24:45.762 E/SharerAct: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
03-06 18:24:45.773 W/SharerAct: SharerActivity: finish
03-06 18:24:45.810 W/ChooserAct: #################################################
03-06 18:24:45.810 W/ChooserAct: ChooserAct: onCreate, sis: null
03-06 18:24:45.810 W/ChooserAct: #################################################
03-06 18:24:45.810 V/FA: onActivityCreated
03-06 18:24:45.841 E/ShrTrgtActvtsAdapter:  ---> Android Beam
03-06 18:24:45.854 E/ShrTrgtActvtsAdapter:  ---> In Google Drive speichern
03-06 18:24:45.865 E/ShrTrgtActvtsAdapter:  ---> Gmail
03-06 18:24:45.874 E/ShrTrgtActvtsAdapter:  ---> Per LAN
03-06 18:24:45.878 E/ShrTrgtActvtsAdapter:  ---> ES Speichern unter
03-06 18:24:45.886 E/ShrTrgtActvtsAdapter:  ---> Inbox
03-06 18:24:45.895 E/ShrTrgtActvtsAdapter:  ---> FolderSync

//... later, after clicking on Gmail

03-06 18:24:54.926 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: org.example.android.my_app_name.app, PID: 21298
 android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/net.cachapa.libra/cache/Libra_2017-03-06.csv exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
     at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1796)
     at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
     at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:845)
     at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8941)
     at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8926)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:791)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:768)
     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:356)
     at org.example.android.my_app_name.app.ui.adapters.ShareTargetActivitiesAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(ShareTargetActivitiesAdapter.java:95)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

So `SharerAct` is reacting to the `android.intent.action.CHOOSER` "broadcast", gets the Intent which is stored in `android.intent.extra.INTENT`, and forwards this intent to `ChooserAct` before finishing.

`ChooserAct`, a Dialog-Themed Activity then builds the dialog by filling the RecyclerView with targets, which were obtained by calling `pm.queryIntentActivities(iIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);` on that forwarded Intent.

When a target app gets clicked, then the following code gets executed

```
m_llLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        int iPosition = (int)view.getTag(R.string.tag_index);
        PackageManager pm = MyApplication.getAppContext().getPackageManager();
        ResolveInfo info = m_ailIRItems.get(iPosition).m_riInfo;
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = info.activityInfo;
        m_iIntent.setClassName(activityInfo.packageName, activityInfo.name); // <- see this?
        m_iIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        //m_iIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //m_iIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
        MyApplication.getAppContext().startActivity(m_iIntent);
        m_dlgAactivityChooser.finish();
    }
});
```

I marked the code above with a `// <- see this?` comment. I don't know if it is OK to do that, basically I'm overriding the target, in case a target was already set. This seems to work, so I'm going with this.

But so you know, the `exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()`-exception listed above occurs on the line `MyApplication.getAppContext().startActivity(m_iIntent);`

My App has access to the file system via a provider:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="org.example.android.my_app_name.files"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/my_paths" />
</provider>
```

Where my_paths is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="files" path="MyAppsHomeFolder/" />
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Initially I only had `MyAppsHomeFolder/` listed there, because there I store backups and stuff that only belongs to the app. But while trying to solve the current issue, I now also added the `<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>` line.

So, I'm pretty clueless here about how I should deal with this `android.os.FileUriExposedException`.

I believe that it has to do with the file being stored in the protected storage of the `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data` folder. But "Andmade Share" is capable of relying that share intent, so there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: A lot of talking. But the for the important intent you omit code. Please show all code for m_iIntent. Why are you not creating that intent in onClick? Please do so. Make it local. Dont use a global pointer. We cannot even see that you use your file provider.

Comment: 1) m_iIntent is local to the recyclerview adapter class, the one which has the onClick in it. I could just as well attach it to `m_llLayout.setTag()` but ATM there is no need for it.

Comment: 2) Not creating in onClick because it is the one passed to me in the `android.intent.extra.INTENT` of the `android.intent.action.CHOOSER` broadcast. This is to not modify anything contained in the extras bundle, like the streams. (there is no more useful code to show) It is a parcelable which I'm passing around.

Comment: `, then Gmail opens up and the photo is in the draft.`. You will not have got/used there a file uri but a content scheme.

Comment: You only get a FileUriExposedException under Android 7 isn't it?

Comment: 6 as well, it also has those restrictions. I'm targeting 7. I fear that I will need to iterate the passed intent to check if I should copy those files into my folder, and then modify the item in the bundle accordingly :(

Comment: I wonder why you posted file provider code. You are not using it.

Comment: If you have such a file uri then you should use your file provider to serve the file. You have to convert the intent. No need to copy files. If you keep with files then you keep the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
"org.example.android.my_app_name.files"  with "${applicationId}.provider" in Manifest file inside  tag

I'm not sure but it might help you :)